# Setka Puzzle - Complete grid using clues and sudoku-style logic; Tom Hanks

Tags: logical-deduction, wordplay, sudoku, crosswords, logic-grid

Theme: Tom Hanks

This is a Setka puzzle; you can find more (along with a more detailed explanation of the rules) at our website, linked from our profile.

How to play Setka, the short version:

Answer each clue using only Puzzle Letters and vowels.

Clue answers, minus vowels and duplicate letters, go in the corresponding boxes in the grid. Only Puzzle Letters go in the grid!

Puzzle Letters can be entered forward/backward/up/down/L-shape, but not jumbled. They also cannot repeat in a row or column.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [image]
>
>
>  1. Sushi 
>  2. Knee 
>  3. Ken 
>  4. Shun 
>  5. Son 
>  6. Hike 
>  7. K(athleen) K(elly) 
>  8. Shoe

Comment: Nice job! Hope you enjoyed the puzzle. Minor note - I think it's Kathleen Kelly?

Comment: @SetkaGames That's right, I've edited it. Great puzzle idea, I'll definitely play more.

Comment: @SetkaGames The [website](http://setkagames.com/setka-tom-hanks/) seems to have an error with this puzzle. The letters for #8 in the expected solution are swapped making the puzzle have duplicates in 2 columns. https://i.imgur.com/0NW2AhY.png

Comment: You're right! Thank you for catching that. It is fixed.